# How to pass parameter from controller to view that doesnot contain initComponent?

Tags: extjs

I am loading a view and passing parameter like :

```
items :[{
         xtype: <xtype>,
         param: <param>
       }]
```

How can I retrieve the param in the included view if that doesn't have initComponent().

I have to pass the retrieved param to other view like:

```
items: [{
        xtype: <xtype1>,
        flex: 5,
        margin: '0 0 5 0',
        rParam: param
       }]
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you need it during definition time or at runtime. `param` does not exist at definition time as a member of the first item so you need a variable to hold the value for both items.

At runtime, `param` is a simple member of the first item so you ca address it as `item1.param`